# Intersection of raster and vector - road file and maps (tif)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, vector

ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1

I have a railroad vector layer (with 10 rows, that is 10 segments) and 30 USGS historic maps (tif files) that cover that route. I'd like to find the intersection, such that one of the attributes in the vector layer is where it crosses these tif files. That is, which maps do I need to use to digitize each section of the road.

I'd like the attribute table in the vector file to list the name of the tif file. I have attached an image.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on this forum response here [How to intersect a raster and vector](https://community.esri.com/thread/190982-how-to-intersect-a-raster-and-vector)

You can use the [Raster to Polygon tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/raster-to-polygon.htm). Which can result in many shapefile/polygons but in your case may not be an issue

> Converts a raster dataset to polygon feature

[image]

An alternative is using the [Zonal Statistics](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/zonal-statistics.htm)

> Calculates statistics on values of a raster within the zones of another dataset.

[image]

Once you have your polyline and polygon, you can use [Intersect Tool](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/how-intersect-analysis-works.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_5F957F68D65949C1A5F431B3DD402B73) , specifically the mixed geometry option

> **Examples: Mixed geometry inputs**
> Intersect can be used with feature classes of different geometries. The default (and highest allowable) Output Type is the same as the feature class with the lowest dimension geometry.
>
> **Polygon and line input for line output**
> The graphic below illustrates the result of intersecting line and polygon feature classes with the Output Type parameter set to LINE. The output line features are where a line from one of the input feature classes overlaps a polygon from the other input feature class.

[image]

Comment: Zonal Statistics let's me only select one raster. I need to select multiple rasters (30?). I did find the raster domain tool, so I can create polygons from my tif files, but I still need to find the intersection of this polyline with all my polygons. Select by location selects them based on the whole line (not each row or section of my line).

Comment: I've updated my answer, you should be able to find the intersection of your polyline and all of your polygon, using the intersect tool?